# Output from array by index returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to output a specific index of an array located in a json object.

For example, I got the following json object which i retreive from MongoDB

```
{ _id: 55b65199c92d15d80fd94803,
  site: 'test.com',
  company: 'test',
  __v: 0,
  votes: [
     { vote_user: '55a11de3e4c770982730ccb9' },
     { vote_user: '55a11de3e4c770982730612a' } 
  ] 
}
```

This object is passed from nodejs route render as an object named suggestion and is through EJS looped through using

```
 <% suggestion.forEach(function(item){ %><%}%>
```

at this stage, I try to retrieve a specific vote_user object from the votes array using

```
 <% suggestion.forEach(function(item){ %><%- item.votes[0] %><%})%>
```

however, all I get is *undefined*

I've tried to assign 'item' to a javascript variable instead and then log it to the browser console, which works exactly as I want and expect it to - as in i get the following result:

```
Object {vote_user: "55a11de3e4c770982730ccb9"}
```

Really can't get around to why it doesn't work as I presume.

## EDIT

As it was a bit unclear how the setup looked like, here's the actual code in use:

#### EJS

```
<% suggestion.forEach(function(item, i){ %>
        <div class="suggestion-entry suggestion-<%- item._id %>" data-entry="<%- item._id %>">
            <!--<%- item %>-->
            <div class="entry-info">
                <div class="voting">
                    <script>
                        console.log(<%- item.votes %>[0].vote_user)
                    </script>
                    <%- item.votes[0].vote_user %>
                    <div class="vote vote-up"><a><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a></div>
                <div class="vote vote-down"><a><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="image"><img src='http://placehold.it/130x90.jpg'></div>
                <div class="company">
                    <h2><a href="<%= item.site %>"><%= item.company %></a></h2>
                    <span class="desc"><%= item.company %></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% }); %>
```

The script tag outputs the actual vote_user value rather than undefined.

#### Nodejs route

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        Suggestion.find(function(err, suggestions){
            res.render('index', { message: req.flash('message'), title: "title", user : req.user, suggestion : suggestions });
        })
    });
```

MongoDB document is as written at the beginning

Comment: Since `item` gives you `{vote_user: "55a11de3e4c770982730ccb9"}` it seems your `suggestion` variable is really your `votes` array. So at some point you probably did something like `suggestion = myJson.votes`

Comment: Thanks @Jan. The thing is, `item` returns the entire object as expected. So when i go `item.votes` I get the votes array in return so in this case `[ { vote_user: '55a11de3e4c770982730ccb9' }, { vote_user: '55a11de3e4c770982730612a' } ]`. As said though, native javascript seems to handle this just fine, although when trying to do the exact same with EJS, it simply doesn't work which I find weird.

Comment: I don't know the syntax of EJS but is it possible that `<%-` should be `<%=` ?

Comment: Tried both but neither works better than the other. `<%-` returns the value unescaped whilst `<%=` returns it escaped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally managed to solve this - I'm not certain of to why this solution works but it does the trick.

Based on what @Jan had adviced, the `id` had to get converted to a string to make EJS be able to validate and work with the json object correctly.

The solution was to first stringify the json object passed from node

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Suggestion.find(function(err, suggestions){
        res.render('index', { message: req.flash('message'), title: "title", user : req.user, suggestion : JSON.stringify(suggestions) });
    })
});
```

This returns all objects and arrays as strings rather than the data type set for the values in mongo.

To be able to work with the string values, I then in EJS simply parsed the stringified suggestion variable as JSON with

```
JSON.parse(suggestion)
```

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER TO EDITED QUESTION:

First off, your `id` needs to be a string. And it seems the problem is with using the `<%-` tags. Maybe you can find documentation of how that is supposed to work but testing on the site, that didn't work at all while `<%=` works perfectly. Stripped down proof of concept:

```
<%
var suggestion = [{ _id: '55b65199c92d15d80fd94803',
  site: 'test.com',
  company: 'test',
  __v: 0,
  votes: [
     { vote_user: '55a11de3e4c770982730ccb9' },
     { vote_user: '55a11de3e4c770982730612a' } 
  ] 
}];
%>

<% suggestion.forEach(function(item, i){ %>
<div class="suggestion-entry suggestion-<%= item._id %>" data-entry="<%= item._id %>">
  <li><%= item.votes[0].vote_user %></li>
  <li><%= item.site %></li>
  <li><%= item.company %></li> 
</div>
<% }); %>
```

Paste it into the testing textarea on the site and you'll see it works. If this still doesn't work with your code, there's something completely different going on.

Comment: Thanks for digging deeper and for pointing out the missing paranthesis, was missing this in the sample I gave but it's there in the source i'm working with, would've gotten errors otherwise :)
Also, thanks for your advice, gave it a try but express returns _Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined_.
So it's pretty much back at step one again. :(

Comment: Additionally, the _id is automatically created by Mongoose in correlation with MongoDB and it is a string already.

Comment: The exact code I posted works if you paste it into the syntax checker on the EJS site. So if you're still having problems, it's not with this part.

Comment: Yea, you're right. It seems to work if you assign the object to a variable directly with EJS, but for some reason, when the object is passed from node, it doesn't so i'm kinda at loss. Thanks for your effort though.

Comment: ...they might be executed at different times in the application cycle? F.e if your EJS runs at DOM load and your node code at document load, the EJS will have executed before the object exists?

Comment: Good point, but don't think that's the case as I can output e.g company and site through `item.site` and `item.company`

Comment: Then you should post the code that you're actually using. This code works.

Comment: Yes @Jan, I'm sorry about that. I've update the post, please see the **edit**

Comment: Like I said originally, change `<%-` to `<%=` and it works. Your `item.company` etc work because you output them with `<%=`

Comment: Yup, sure works when the variable is specified inline in EJS, but when the object is from nodejs/mongoDB it doesn't - possibly because the _id isn't a string but I don't really see why e.g company can be outputted then. Thanks for your help so far, hopefully I'll work this out.

Comment: If those other properties on the object work as advertised, then the rest of the object can't look like what you've posted. If it did, it would work. What's the output if you parse just `<%= item.votes %>`? It should look something like `[Object, Object]`